# "One should warn" vs. "it should warn"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns

Can you explain to me when it is more appropriate to use *it* or *one* in the following sentence?

> One/it should warn about the conflicts.

I don't think there's a big deal using one or another because the meaning will be exactly the same.

Comment: There are _very_ few contexts where "one" and "it" are interchangeable.

Comment: You might be interested in supporting our proposed spin-off site targeted specifically at [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2).

Comment: I think neither this question can be tagged with [usage] nor its title can be "_Usage_: One vs it", nor it is possible to base a comparison ("vs") between the two pronoun. @RegDwight

Comment: What Colin said. I think there are *no* contexts where "one" and "it" are interchangeable as subjects of "should warn". This question is General Reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The meaning is *not* exactly the same. *One* used as a pronoun indicates an unspecified single person, whereas *it* indicates a specific object or collective.

It's hard to tell exactly what the context is here with such a short quote, but

> One should warn about the conflicts.

means that someone should warn others about the conflicts.

> It should warn about the conflicts.

means that a device or software program, or perhaps office or organization, which was previously being discussed, should warn about the conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

"One" should be used exclusively to refer to people (or people-like things - pets, etc).  "It" should never be used to refer to people.

Caveat: "One" can refer to non-people-like things in cases like, "One should warn about conflicts and the other should do something else".